# Can I pass a PHP associative array to a ComVisible .NET function?

Tags: c#, php, .net, f#, com

When I pass a PHP indexed array:

```
$myVar = new COM('MyClass');
$myVar->DubbleArray([1, 2]);
```

...it comes through to C# or F# as an System.Object[], and I can deal with it accordingly, e.g.:

```
[<ComVisible(true)>]
type LettersClass() = 
    member this.DubbleArray(array: obj[]) =
    // do stuff with the values in the array
```

But when I pass an associative array:

```
$myVar->DubbleArray(array('first'=>'1st','second'=>'2nd'));
```

...it comes through as DBNull.

**Is there any way to pass an associative array to a .NET function via COM?**

Answer (score 1):

Using a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) in .NET allows you to deal with named keys. You could always encode the data in JSON format then decode in .NET as well... :)

(Note: this answer is based off of not seeing any .net in your question)

Comment: Is there any easier/safer/more efficient way to pass them BETWEEN PHP and .NET than e.g. JSON serialization?

Comment: I'm not familiar with any other way. It's probably possible, you might want to tag your question with .NET

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it really falls on how marshalling of an associative array is handled on the PHP side. The actual answer very well might be "not at all".

Unless you can figure that out, I would suggest a workaround - my best bet would be to convert the associative array to a multidimensional array storing keys and values in separate columns, and passing that through as an `obj[,]`.